# Erro ao somar campos Edit Text usando OnFocusChangeListener

Tags: java, android, edittext

Estou tentando fazer com que minha aplicação calcule o campos `EditText` preço de custo mais percentual de lucro e ao clicar no campo preço de venda já apareça o resultado, porém ao invés de aparecer o resultado aparece a seguinte mensagem no edit text do campo:

> android.widget.EditText@41f

Obrigado a quem puder ajudar de forma mais específica possível pois não tenho experência.

```
  OnFocusChangeListener focusListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {

                custo = MonetaryMask.stringMonetarioToDouble(edPrecoDeCusto.getText().toString());
                lucro = MonetaryMask.stringMonetarioToDouble(edPercDeLucro.getText().toString());
                venda = MonetaryMask.stringMonetarioToDouble(edPrecoDeVenda.getText().toString());

                venda = calcularLucro(custo, lucro);
                edPrecoDeVenda.setText(edPrecoDeVenda.toString());

            }

        }
    };


   edPercDeLucro.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);      


    private double calcularLucro(double custo, double lucro) {
             venda = custo + lucro / 100 * custo;
      return venda;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está passando a `String` com a referencia de memória do objeto:

```
edPrecoDeVenda.toString()
```

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
 edPrecoDeVenda.setText(venda);
```

Com o `getText()`, você irá pegar o valor do campo !

Comment: Eu fiz como tu sugeriu porém ele não está realizando o cálculo. Não está dando o erro mas também não realiza o cálculo, alguma sugestão ?  @Thiago Luiz Domacoski

Comment: tente assim: **edPrecoDeVenda.setText(venda);** Pois você seta o calculo nesta variável, certo?

Comment: Editei a resposta também !

Comment: Muito Obrigado !! 100%  @ Thiago Luiz Domacoski